# Nested Resources in ember-cli, messy app structure

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

As a newbie to both Ember.js and ember-cli, I'm having trouble making sense of what seems necessary to make my app work.

The logical hierarchy of my app is something like this:

```
Projects
|___Project
    |___Details
    |___Team Members
    |___Budget
        |___Planned
        |___Actual
```

And currently, this is my router.js:

```
  this.resource('projects');
  this.resource('project', { path: 'projects/:project_id' }, function() {
    this.route('details');
    this.route('team');
    this.route('milestones');
    this.resource('budget', function(){
      this.route('project-budget', { path: 'project'});
      this.route('resource-budget', {path: 'team'});
    });
  });
```

What I'm having trouble with is where to put my files. Up until the point of the two nested routes under Budget, my folder structure looked like my hierarchy, but since a Resource resets the namespace, now to make it work I have to pull my Budget template, route, and controller back out to the top level (with Projects stuff), which just seems messy and like it will cause headaches when trying to maintain this thing later.

Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: The budget resource seems out of place,none of your resources nested in `project` are using a dynamic segment, why are they there in the first place.

Comment: @PatsyIssa: because they are all pieces belonging to a project, so project/details, project/team, etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Router definition can be a little tricky in Ember.  Your resource/route definition in router.js should reflect your page structure.  So for example, if your 'team' template should be nested inside your 'project' template, then 'team' should be nested inside of 'project' in router.js:

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('project', function() {
         this.route('team');
    });
});
```

If you use this.route() in router.js, then your folder structure should mimic the structure in router.js.  Using the example above, because we're using this.route() to define 'team', your folder structure would be like this:

```
app/routes/project.js
app/routes/project/team.js
app/templates/project.hbs
app/templates/project/team.hbs
```

If, however, you choose to use use this.resource() in router.js, then you're telling Ember that you're going to reset your folder structure.  So if you changed router.js to this:

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('project', function() {
         this.resource('team');
    });
});
```

...then your folder structure would be like this:

```
app/routes/project.js
app/routes/team.js
app/templates/project.hbs
app/templates/team.hbs
```

Going back to your specific question, if you feel that resetting your folder structure is messy, then you can use this.route() everywhere and forego this.resource(), because nestable this.route() landed in Ember 1.7: http://emberjs.com/blog/2014/08/23/ember-1-7-0-released.html

Comment: I had tried to use 'route' instead of 'resource' (against the ember recommendation to use resources for nouns), but then it complained about needing a resource in order to do something, so I had to switch it back. Ultimately I did have to reset my folder structure to get it to work, but now Budget stuff is at the top level, and Team and Details are within Project. Maybe I need to start using [Pod Structure](http://www.ember-cli.com/#pod-structure), but I'm afraid of really screwing things up with that. I guess with a branch though I shouldn't be scared.

Comment: Nesting this.route() should work fine.  Here's an example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/fobofe/4/edit?html,js  I'm using globals instead of Ember CLI in the jsbin, but the principles are the same.

Comment: What version of Ember are you using? Nestable this.route() was introduced in version 1.7: http://emberjs.com/blog/2014/08/23/ember-1-7-0-released.html

Comment: I had to downgrade to 1.6 for IE8 support.

Comment: IE8 is still supported in the latest version of Ember. In fact, the plan is to still support it in Ember 2.0: https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/pull/15#issuecomment-61613154

Comment: Thanks for this. Was driving me crazy that I couldn't access my nested route because I didn't know that the file structure also had to be nested according to the route.